# Who is the other presumed dead Robin in Powerless?

Tags: dc, powerless-tv

In the Powerless episode "Emily dates a henchman" it is stated that two of Batman's Robins are presumed dead. The obvious choice for one would be Jason Todd, but who is likely the other?

Comment: Note the phrase "Believed to have died".  It's very possible that this universe's Batman has already gone through Dick Grayson and Tim Drake, both of which moved on to other identities, and not died. People saw the sudden change in Robin (suddenly younger, shorter, surlier) and just assume cynically that the last one died.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Damian Wayne

Damian was killed in 2013's [*Batman, Inc* Vol 2 Issue 8](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Incorporated_(Volume_2)_Issue_8)

[image]

In any main comic continuity, he is the only other Robin who has died, and is most likely where Powerless is getting their reference from.

Answer (score 4):

It might be [Stephanie Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephanie_Brown_(comics)). She served as Robin during a time when Tim was unavailable, but came to a tragic end.

> In an effort to prove her worth to Batman, Stephanie steals one of his long-term plans for dealing with the entirety of Gotham's criminal underworld, arranging a meeting to bring them all together. Since this plan is predicated on the involvement of "Matches Malone" who, unbeknownst to her, is a persona that Batman uses to infiltrate the underworld, it quickly spins out of control. The result is a city-wide gang war in which Stephanie is captured by the Black Mask. She is tortured extensively by Black Mask to get information about Batman, as well as learning enough information to allow him to take control of Batman's plan and assume command of the gangs himself. Although she escapes and makes her way to a hospital, she is severely injured, and supposedly dies in a hospital bed as Batman sits beside her.

Of course, in 2007:

> After escaping the ambush, Robin and Batman track down the woman in a bid to force her to stop imitating Stephanie. When confronted, she removes her mask and reveals that she is indeed Stephanie, with Leslie Thompkins having faked her death. Batman reveals his doubts about her death leading him to not erect a memorial for her in the Batcave. Since her secret identity had been compromised, Leslie faked her death so villains could not use her against Batman as Black Mask had done. Living with Leslie in Africa under an alias, Stephanie had been performing volunteer work until an attack from a local witch-hunting tribe prompted her to return to crimefighting, and subsequently to Gotham. Stephanie reunites with her mother, enrolls in Tim's high school, and rejoins the Bat-Family.

However, *Powerless* could be set in between when she was known to have died and before the later revelations. [This review makes the same suggestion](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/powerless-dating-means-sometimes-you-wind-henchman-250930):

> In this DC continuity, Ron states that at least two Robins are suspected to have been killed in action. No way to know at this point, but it seems Jason Todd and Stephanie Brown are the likely, unlucky fallen Robins.

Comment: I wondered this, too, but she goes on to be Batgirl and Spoiler. But the public wouldn't know. But if Damian showed up after her, it's way more obvious She was gone with no explanation. If Damian is used at all, which maybe not because it's complicated, so. Well, +1